# How can I reserve virtual memory in Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, mmap

I have an application that reserves a contiguous memory block using VirtualAllocEx on Windows with the MEM_RESERVE flag.  This reserves a virtual memory block, but does not back it with a physical page or page file chunk.  Hence, accessing the allocated memory will result in a segmentation fault -- but other allocations will not intersect with this virtual memory block.

How can I do the same for Linux with mmap?  I did notice the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914202/how-can-i-reserve-memory-addresses-without-allocating-them), but does that really guarantee that say, 1 GB of physical memory won't be allocated to my process if I don't touch the allocated pages?  I don't want any thrashing problems.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you should be able to achieve the same by mapping anonymous memory with `PROT_NONE`. Accessing `PROT_NONE` memory will result in a segfault, but the memory region will be reserved and not used for any other purpose. If you want to allocate a very big chunk of memory, add `MAP_NORESERVE` to ensure that the default overcommit mechanism won't check your allocation.

`PROT_NONE` is commonly employed for "guard" pages at the end of stacks.

Comment: This is a very interesting technique. By using `mmap(2)` + `PROT_NONE` you basically have the same effects of `VirtualAlloc()` + `MEM_RESERVE` on Windows. I am a little bit more concerned about the `MAP_NORESERVE` flag: while you can set `PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE` with `mprotect(2)` once you need pages (that will be like a call to `VirtualAlloc()`+`MEM_COMMIT`), it seems you cannot reset the flag `MAP_NORESERVE` once you've specified it to a call to `mmap(2)`, so your memory will be set as "no reserve" forever, even when "committed". How would you solve this quirk?

Comment: I think the cleanest solution would be to call mmap again with `MAP_FIXED` and the address/size of the region to allocate/commit. It’s entirely possible to mmap on top of existing regions (replacing any existing mapping in the area) if you use `MAP_FIXED`, and this is a common way of changing mmap flags that can’t be changed via some combination of mlock/mprotect.